# Vertical slider button for aspx (C#)

Tags: c#, jquery, .net, slider

I need to implement a logger feature with 4 levels by adding a vertical slider button going from lower to upper level of logging

This slider has to be placed inside a web page, so I was wondering if there is another solution except jquery UI slider

Comment: jquery works quite well in web pages, is there a particular reason you don't want to use it?

Comment: jquery UI slider is a horizontal solution, I need a vertical one, I really wonder there is not a .NET solution for it

Comment: [jQuery's slider can be vertical](https://jqueryui.com/slider/#slider-vertical)

Comment: that solution is a gradually one, I need a vertical and discret solution (4 levels)

Comment: You would just set `min` and `max` to 1 and 4, and `step` to 1

Answer (score 3):

You could use `<input type="range" />` for this and rotate it with CSS:

```css
input[type="range"] {
  position: absolute;
  top: 100px;
  transform: rotate(270deg);
}
```

```html
<input type="range" min="1" max="4" value="1" />
```

This would be a pure HTML5/CSS3 solution with no need for jQuery.